# How can I unset PYTHONHOME when activating a virtualenv in Windows?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have 64-bit Python 2.7.5 installed at `C:\Python27`.

My environment variables are as follows:

```
Path: %PYTHONHOME%\Scripts;
PYTHONHOME: C:\Python27;
PYTHONPATH: C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk;C:\Python27\DLLs;
```

I created a virtualenv called 'foo', but noticed that `pip freeze` after activating foo showed all the packages from my global installation.

After playing around, it seems that removing the `PYTHONHOME` variable fixes this; `pip freeze` then only sees packages installed in my virtualenv.

However, I currently have to remove `PYTHONHOME` manually.  There is a blurb in the virtualenv's `Scripts\activate` script that should clear it, but doesn't seem to (`$env:PYTHONHOME` before and after activating cheerfully show the same `PYTHONHOME`):

```
# unset PYTHONHOME if set
# this will fail if PYTHONHOME is set to the empty string (which is bad anyway)
# could use `if (set -u; : $PYTHONHOME) ;` in bash
if [ -n "$PYTHONHOME" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME="$PYTHONHOME"
    unset PYTHONHOME
fi
```

How do I clear `PYTHONPATH` automatically?  Does the activate script need to be modified in some way under Windows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When creating the virtual env you can use the --no-site-packages flag as such:

```
virtualenv env_name --no-site-packages
```

Then as is said [in the documentation](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#other-notes)

> ..[the virtualenv] will not include the packages that are installed globally.

Comment: this option is now [deprecated](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/?highlight=no-site-packages#cmdoption-no-site-packages)